# How to pass and return AppleScript record with Java

Tags: java, applescript

Environment

- Yosemite 10.10.3
- Oracle Java 1.8

I have no problems passing and returning single arguments and list using the ScriptBinding hash.

**Question:** I don't see how to pass the equivalent of a AppleScript Record (e.g. {first: "Foo" last: "Bar"}) or, for that matter, receiving one back in Java.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the answer by brute force:

- To send the AppleScript the equivalent of a record, you can set the SimpleBinding "javax.script.argv" to a hash-map. There is a caveat that the keys in the hash-map can not be objects, for example {"arg1" 7, 8 [9])
- To receive a record back from AppleScript, just return it from the script. It will be coerced to a hash-map.

I will test further and add any notable information as comments to this answer.

Comment: can you provide a sample for it..?